# Spring boot @Transactionnal imbrication bad practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I'm developing a JEE app with Spring boot.
I just want to be sure that there will be any problem to imbricate functions annoted @Transactionnal ? It is a bad practice ?

In my example, I want to save a Relationship between two User and if I call the last function, it will imbricate three transaction.

```
@Transactional
public PrRelationship save(Relationship r)
{
    Relationship result = this.relationshipRepo.save(r);

    return result;
}

@Transactional
public Relationship save(Relationship r, User relation)
{
    this.userService.save(relation);

    r.setUser(user);
    r.setUserRelation(relation);
    return this.save(r);
}

@Transactional
public Relationship save(Relationship r, User user, User relation) {
    this.userService.save(user);
    return this.save(r, relation);
}
```

Thank you for your advices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some reading on [Transaction Propagation and Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation) in Spring. It will answer these kinds of questions.

To answer your question, the default propagation is `REQUIRED` which means that any calls to transactional methods from a method that creates a transaction will execute on that same transaction. So in your case, they will "imbricate" (I had to look that word up).

Comment: Thank you for your advice ;-)